# I want to copy the latest file saved in folder and paste to another folder

Tags: vbscript

I have one folder named "Source" and I want to copy the latest file saved in this folder to another folder named "Destination" using VBScript.

I am using the code for copy and paste as below but I didn't get it to copy the latest file.

```
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
objFSO.DeleteFile "D:\Destination\Book1.xlsx"
objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Source\Book1.xlsx", "D:\Destination\Book1.xlsx"
```

Comment: The code you posted isn't VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your code is VBA. So maybe you are using it from Excel?

VBScript is different syntax.

This will move your file to the test-folder:

```
set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.copyfile "d:\bat\test.txt", "d:\bat\test\test.txt"
```

You can put this code in a text file with the .vbs ending. Then you can execute it from a command line.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx) describes how to use the filesystemobject. You don't need to delete the file first. It will be overwritten by default by the copyfile method.